# Win32 App Can't Render Font/Image Properly

Tags: windows, winapi, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, win32gui

I have this win32 application. I created an installer for it and in my computer it works perfectly fine. I can install and run it. However, when someone I know tried installing it, the application ran but with user interface issues. 
 [image: This is how it looked like. I didn't add the white boxes or the weird lines.] 
 This is how it looked like. I didn't add the white boxes nor the weird lines. 
 Does anyone of you know the reason why this happened? I have no clue at all T_T. Is there a way to prevent this from happening again? 
 By the way, the UI was made using cocos studio. I'm using cocos2d-x for this app.

Comment: Quite frankly - they need to update their Video card drivers.

Comment: Does your install include all dependent redistributable dlls?

Comment: @rrirower yes it does. in fact, i had no issue installing it or whatsoever. it just happened in one pc.